# Redirecting to an external URL while keeping original URL in address bar using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I am trying to do to is forward my visitors to a new domain, but while keeping the old one in the users address bar.

Basically how an iframe would work, but using htaccess.

I've tried the following pieces of code, however with all the URL in the address bar changes.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]`

and

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 / http://mynewdomain.com/`

I'm looking to link to an external URL with a specific path.

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy loaded? If not, your `P` flag won't do anything

Comment: I don't, will look into it, not sure what it is haha